# Check if a number is missing from a non-sorted league

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, datagridview

I have a datagridview displayed on the screen.  The user can change the end column called "Pareto" to any integer he/she likes.  But there is a catch, all records are in a league.
The user also may wish to simply leave a number out and come back to it, so not allowing for a missing number isn't possible.

Basically I need a method that checks if a column has a missing number from a non-sorted row, and also stores each number that's missing into an array/list for me to output.

Normally I like these little logic questions But after the loops I've coded today my brain is burnt out... so any input would be great!

I originally thought about first getting the maximum records in the grid via count(no problem)

Then using it as the range from 1 - "maxCount".  Find all missing numbers. It sounded so simple until I thought about the fact it is not sorted.

Many thanks

Comment: What are the rules for the numbers? They have to be sequential? Like if there are ten rows I should see the numbers 1 to 10 each one time?

Comment: rules are 500 rows, should contain 1-500 numbers that are unique. But they dont have to be in order, they could flow like this. 1,2,8,3,4,10,5,7,6,9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not clear the **real** work-flow, but..

The fact is that `DataGridView` is *not* sorted is a pure `UI` stuff. Your `data` *can* be sorted and binded to the `DataGrid` via `DataView` or any other intermidiate `View` layer.

One time user inserts the value, you can execute binary-search (fastest available on sorted collection search) to find the value of interest.

**EDIT**

If you need to check the missed numbers among set of numbers from (1..500), first you can have all numbers sorted, like defined in my post in data-model.

```
List<int> sortedAlreadyAvailableNumbers ...
```

after make

```
var missingNumbers =  Enumerable.Range(1, 500).Except(sortedAlreadyAvailableNumbers );
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: wait, I thought a binary search is based upon you already knowing what the item is your looking for, and that the search only locates its index. In my case I'm searching for any Missing numbers but I do not know what these numbers are.

Comment: ah I see so the problem isn't so much the methodology of searching for missing data but rather the fact it isn't sorted data.

Comment: @StevenSmith: well in this way it will work even if *not* sorted, but with sorted data it will work much faster.